# RECORD_AUDIO permission denied for a system app

Tags: android, speech-recognition

I'm getting this error when I'm trying to use SpeechRecognition for a system app

```
Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Proxy package com.google.android.katniss from uid 10038 or calling package android.uid.system from uid 1000 not allowed to perform RECORD_AUDIO
```

I'm requesting Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO permission as usual before using SpeechRecognition API and it is working fine when the app is in debug. This is the code I'm using

```
    val audioPermissionStatus = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(requireContext(), Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO)
    val showRationale = shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO)

    when {
        audioPermissionStatus == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED -> {
            val intent = Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH).apply {
                putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL, RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM)
                putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_PARTIAL_RESULTS, true)
                putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_SPEECH_INPUT_COMPLETE_SILENCE_LENGTH_MILLIS, 3500)
            }
            lazySpeechRecognizer.value.startListening(intent)
            showSpeechDialog()
        }
        showRationale -> showPermissionDialog()
        else -> requestPermissions(arrayOf(Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO), 0)
    }
```

Permission is granted when permission dialog appears, but then that exception is thrown

Comment: Permissions can still be denied for a system app. The user can choose not to grant any runtime permission to any app.

Comment: It's is granted when permission dialog appears, but then that exception is thrown